# Trailing Image in Graphics.drawImage() method

Tags: java, graphics, java-3d

I have an image that I need to move by calling:

```
int Y = 100;
Graphics g = Canvas().getGraphics(); //Canvas is a Java 3D Canvas 3D
g.drawImage(Image, 400, Y, Canvas);
```

I also have a keylistener that moves the image, but whenever the image moves it leaves behind a trail of images. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `getGraphics`, this is at best a snap shot of the last paint cycle and at worst `null`.  Painting should be done within the appropriate paint methods (in Swing that would be `JComponent#paintComponent`).  Yo may need to provide some context to the question to get an appropriate answer

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing much important information from your question forcing us to guess, and this is not a good thing. My guess: If you are drawing this in a `paint(...)` or `paintComponent(...)` method, then you must first call the super method.